# A Google Maps icon is in the wrong place - how can I suggest it be moved?

Tags: google-maps

I've noticed that when doing either the Satellite or Map views on Google Maps, sometimes the icon indicating where a particular business is located is just wrong: off not by yards, but by hundreds or thousands of yards.

What is the process for moving those icons to where they "should" be?

Comment: Do they have the correct address for the business?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Right-click on the map marker and click the Report a Problem link.  There's a little form to submit right inline on the map that lets you tell them about the problem.

Comment: I knew it couldn't be *that* hard... thanks!